# Am I able to answer my own question and then mark it as accepted?

Tags: support

Yeah I want to know if it is cheating to answer my own question and then accept it.

Comment: This post on Meta Stack Exchange explains it: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes. This is completely allowed.**

Quoting from the [Help Centre *Can I answer my own question?*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer):

> Stack Exchange [has always explicitly encouraged users](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site. […]
>
> You can also [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!

To avoid people abusing this, there are a few limitations:

- You have to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer, compared to the usual [15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50697/226928).
- If you accept an answer from somebody else, you get +2 rep and they get +15 rep. You don’t get either of those if you accept your own answer.
- Normally the accepted answer is shown at the top of the list of answers, even if it has less votes than other answers. You don’t get that if you self-accept – your answer is sorted according to its vote count.

Answer (score 5):

It isn’t cheating. Go ahead, if you think your answer is better than any other answers. There is a two-day waiting period between posting your question and being able to accept your own answer, but other than that, there are no restrictions.

There’s even an “Answer your own question” checkbox when writing a question that specifically allows you to do this.

A few differences (from sumelic):

- You don’t gain any reputation when you accept your own answer.
- Your self-answer won’t move to the top of the list of answers, unless it has more upvotes than any other answer.